# How to trigger the UICollectionView focus api delegate methods on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been playing around with the focus api in `UICollectionView` and I've been unable to get the delegate methods to trigger. Unfortunately the documentation is rather sparse.

I have a custom `UIViewController` subclass in which I implement the follow:

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    return storedCellReference != nil ? [storedCellReference] : super.preferredFocusEnvironments
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
          canFocusItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool { return true }

func collectionView(UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusIn: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool { return true }

func collectionView(UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) { 

// custom animation code here
}
```

In the collection view delegate didSelect handler, I'm storing a reference to the cell and calling `view.setNeedsFocusUpdate()` yet none of the focus api methods are hitting breakpoints. Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: You can use custom background view to focus on collectionview cell ,use some flag in array modal for currently selecting the view and using that change the property of cell of background view like color

Comment: Is it even possible to set focus on iOS? The collection view apis exist but some focus specific properties are only available for tvOS

Comment: Yes you can do easily by putting custom background view and highlight based on user tap on cell. Like when user tap on cell set modal selected property in modal for that indexpath and reload . In cellForRowAtIndexPath change the color property of background view based on array modal for that indexpath. Other indexpath modal selected bool property will be false.You can check this url https://s3.amazonaws.com/poly-screenshots.angel.co/Project/77/434877/fe5261e73234dce9b30630a42bd8d4d1-original.PNG

Comment: The question was how to use the focus api, not how to set a custom background view.

Comment: ok i now i understood.